chrome ignores local DNS despite flag settings
The DNS server to which my system is pointing maps example.com to a private IP address.
dig example.com => (private LAN IP address)
However, Chrome appears to refuse to use the system DNS.  Testing with chrome://net-internals/#dns shows example.com => (public IP address).
I have searched the solutions from similar questions which suggest modifying some of the following flags:
Async DNS resolver
Enables the built-in DNS resolver. – Windows, Linux

#enable-async-dns

and tried disabling HTTPS DNS:
Use DNS https alpn
When enabled, Chrome may try QUIC on the first connection using the ALPN information in the DNS HTTPS record. – Mac, Windows, Linux, ChromeOS, Android

#use-dns-https-svcb-alpn

I have also disabled secure DNS from the settings.
After restarting the browser, initially chrome appeared to resolve example.com to the correct private IP address. But some time later, chrome appears to have reverted back to using Google's public DNS and mapping example.com to the wrong address.
How can I stop Chrome from disrespecting the system's DNS configuration?

I was able to reproduce the issue after the local DNS server went down briefly. Chrome fell back to the public DNS server, and continued to do so even after the system DNS server had come back up. Even resetting the cache at chrome://net-internals -> DNS did not help.
